# Cypress Blob gives error Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window', with mkv file

Tags: blob, cypress, web-api-testing, mkv

I need to test API, with a MKV file in the request.

I use the following code for that:

```
        cy.fixture('video.mkv').then(file => {
            const blob = Cypress.Blob.base64StringToBlob(file, "video/x-matroska")
            cy.request({
                method: ...
                url: ...
                body: blob,
            })

        });
```

Finally, I have this error:

"InvalidCharacterError
Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range."

I'm not sure that, for MKV file, I should convert base64 strings to Blob objects.

FYI: I test with Cypress v10.0.0
Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `arrayBufferToBlob`

```js
cy.fixture('video.mkv').then(file => {
  const blob = Cypress.Blob.arrayBufferToBlob(file, "video/x-matroska")
  cy.request({...
})
```

These are the available [Blob functions](https://github.com/nolanlawson/blob-util#functions), and `arrayBufferToBlob` looks likely (at least, no errors).

Try out other methods if no-go on this one.

Comment: Thanks! Now, I can send a video in the request.

However, the file in not properly converted to blob, as the output video is damaged.
Note that:
- input size = ~200kB
- output size = ~700kB

Comment: It could be a Cypress Blob issue, with arrayBufferToBlob

Comment: Not sure the size is a good indicator, since the content is transformed there could well be a difference. But yeah, I'm only guessing as to which transform method to use - I assume you looked at some of the other methods?

Comment: I've tried to use binaryStringToBlob, with the same issue than base64StringToBlob.

At least, The request works with arrayBufferToBlob, but the file is damaged.

It's the only methods, that i can use, as I need blob object.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, with a MKV file, it appears that I don't need to convert to blob object, as the request is well sent with this file:

```
    cy.fixture('video.mkv').then(file => {
        cy.request({
            method: ...
            url: ...
            body: **file**,
        })

    });
```

However, the video is always damaged after the request.
Here are file content for comparison, before and after:

Original content:
[image]

Output content:
[image]

We can see that a part was modified, like 'A3' at the beginning, replaced by 'EF BF BD'

**Note that this service works fine, ouside Cypress, and we are able to retrieve output video.**